# Python upload image to AWS - Image becomes black / corrupted

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, base64, image-upload

I am trying to upload an image to AWS either as base64 string or as image but after the upload the image corrupts / becomes black.

```
for item in os.listdir(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'])):
    if item.startswith(str(current_user.id)):
        with open(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], item)) as thefile:
            data = base64.b64encode(thefile.read())
            upload_image_to_aws_from_image_v3('MYBUCKET', "userimg/", data, new_zimmer, "hauptbild", new_zimmer.stadt, new_zimmer.id)
```

The method for AWS:

```
def upload_image_to_aws_from_image_v3(bucketname, bucketpath, image_from_form, model_to_change, model_column, model_addon_for_name, model_addon_for_name_id):

    s3 = boto.connect_s3(app.config['MY_AWS_ID'], app.config['MY_AWS_SECRET'], host='s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com')

    bucket_name = bucketname
    bucket = s3.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    k = Key(bucket)

    #file_contents = image_from_form.read()

    the_filename = "zimmer-" + model_addon_for_name.lower().strip() + str(model_addon_for_name_id) + ".jpg" 

    filename_hauptbild = secure_filename(the_filename)    

    k.key = bucketpath + filename_hauptbild  

    k.set_contents_from_string(image_from_form)

    setattr(model_to_change, model_column, filename_hauptbild)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following and see if you get better results:

```
import boto

def upload_image_to_aws_from_image_v3(bucketname, bucketpath, image_from_form, model_to_change, model_column, model_addon_for_name, model_addon_for_name_id):

    s3 = boto.connect_s3(app.config['MY_AWS_ID'], app.config['MY_AWS_SECRET'], host='s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com')
    bucket = s3.get_bucket(bucket_name)

    the_filename = "zimmer-" + model_addon_for_name.lower().strip() + str(model_addon_for_name_id) + ".jpg"

    filename_hauptbild = secure_filename(the_filename)

    k = bucket.new_key(key_name)
    k.set_contents_from_string(image_from_form)
    k.set_contents_from_filename(path_to_file)
    return k
```